# How to Organize a Book Driven Group Study at work

Tags: career-development, human-resources, training, team-building

I have gotten the green light from management about organizing a Study Group for following the Chapters of specific programming book, and also U have communicated back to the team.

What else should I do?

Should we just seat together and start following the book together?

From other people's experience, I would like get the dynamics of the actual group together.

- We are using the Company's meeting room
- We have a physical book at the company
- We have the digital copy in the company
- most developers have notebooks.

We will have one and a half hour once a week.

**Goals**

- Learn the Topic of the Book, since it has a lot of exercises, do the exercises. What is not clear to me is if we read together, or how we go over the explanations, etc...
- Team Build, having developers together self organizing the group
- Create a feeling of learning, and show that company is investing on them, since we are authorized to use paid time to do the group.

Comment: Hi @JoeStrazzere The Goal is to learn the Topic of the Book, since it has a lot of exercises, do the exercises. What is not clear to me is if we read together, or how we go over the explanations, etc...

Comment: The core question here has nothing to do with the workplace. The fact that the study group happens to be at a workplace is of miniscule relevance. Replace workplace with a pub, a garden or a club, and the question doesn't change. Hence, not only is it not clear what kind of answers you are looking for, but it is also not clear what workplace-specific issue you need help with. Reopen voter needs to explain. :)

Comment: One of the goals is Team Building, and the Skills acquired in the Group are supposed to be used in the Job. :) 
@MaskedMan  - I have edited  the questions

Answer (score 1):

The last time I did this:

- There were novices reading the book to learn the subject
- There were also experts (who already knew the whole subject and the book) participating
- We read about a chapter or two per week (in our own time)
- The communal "discussion" was to ask and answer any questions anyone might have about the chapter

Since everyone in your study group works for the same company, you might find it good to use your time together to discuss how to apply what you read in the book to a shared development project.

I might also (though I don't know how to tie this into a study group) recommend you look at a well-written real-world example of whatever the book is describing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for success of such group you need willing participants eager to learn and  a local expert (or experts).

The group splits the book into several parts and agrees on a review schedule.

The group reads an agreed upon number of chapters on their own and  prepare questions for the discussion.

During the review session the group addresses participant questions and discusses the material.

It is expected that the local expert(s) should be able to help the group with any difficulties they cannot sort out on their own.